# Popup menu when pressing / selection any text on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Is there a way to popup a menu whenever user selects text on an Andriod device?

e.g. When user press down long on any text, default popup menu appear which contains; Copy, Cut, Paste...etc.

Is there a way to add another entry on that "Context Menu" that launches my app when pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no facilities for adding your app to the OS default context menu in Android. You can set [intent receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your AndroidManifest.xml that will 'listen' for certain actions and intercept them if allowed. For this reason, sometimes clicking icons or filesystem assets will prompt you with a chooser to select an application to open with.